# How to restart count midway through a string of input?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to write a function that recieves any length string of positive or negative whole numbers and adds each number to the total, as long as the value doesn't go below zero. (It returns 0 for any invalid or empty input.)

I'm having trouble writing a loop that re-sets the count to zero when it becomes negative and continutes adding from where it left off.

e.g. 
input: `1, 2, -4, 1, 1` 
output: `2`

Here's my code:

```
def sum_earnings():
values = input("Enter a string of pos &/or neg numbers separated by commas (e.g. 1,-3,0,-4): ").split(',')
earnings = 0

try:
    for i in values:
        earnings += int(i)
        while earnings >= 0:
            earnings += int(i)
        else:
            earnings = 0
            continue
    print(earnings)

except ValueError:
    print(0)

return
```

Comment: ur indentation is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that and changed it a bit to correct for unneccesary code.

Comment: I'm unclear what you want to do - does it produce 0 if the running total _ever_ drops below zero? In which case, why do you need to pick it up again? 

Also, yes, your indent is wrong there :)

Comment: Ah, I see now you've added a concrete example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems overly complicated. Try the following:

```
earnings = 0
for i in values:
    try:
        earnings = max(0, earnings + int(i))  # resets to 0 for negative intermediate sum
    except ValueError:
        earnings = 0
        break  # this will end the loop for invalid input
print(earnings)
```